# Polymer: Stop children from toggling mouseenter/out events

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events

I have a Polymer component that has listeners to `on-mouseenter` and `on-mouseout`.

```
listeners: {
    mouseenter: 'mouseEnter',
    mouseout: 'mouseOut',
}
```

and:

```
mouseEnter: function (e) {
    console.log('\n\nENTER');
    this.$.deleteBtn.style.display = 'block';
},

mouseOut: function (e) {
    console.log('\n\nOUT');
    this.$.deleteBtn.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Inside that are multiple other elements.

The issue is, that the events trigger for all child elements and not only the parent container. Especially the `mouseout` seems to trigger multiple times.
I only want them to be triggered when the host is entered or exited, not for all individual children. Otherwise causes all kinds of unexpected behaviour.

This could be solved, if I didnt use the Polymer listeners, but as I would like to be consistent and have the proper scope, this is not really an option.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`, because `mouseout` is triggered for each child element.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp) for more info.